# How to style android actionbar overflow menu

Tags: android, android-styles

Im learning android through official documentation. The problem is, `android:popupMenuStyle` does not work. I tried everything I found about this, like using `android:actionBarWidgetTheme`, but none of them solved my problem.
heres my style:

```
    <resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <style name="CustomTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/CustomTheme.ActionBar</item>
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/CustomTheme.ActionBar</item>
        <item name="android:actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/CustomTheme.ActionBar.ActionOverflowButtonStyle</item>
        <item name="actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/CustomTheme.ActionBar.ActionOverflowButtonStyle</item>
        <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/CustomTheme.ActionBar.PupopMenuStyle</item>
        <item name="popupMenuStyle">@style/CustomTheme.ActionBar.PupopMenuStyle</item>
        <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    </style>
    <style name="CustomTheme.ActionBar.PupopMenuStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.PopupMenu">
        <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/action_bar_background</item>
    </style>
        ...
    </resources>
```

My min SDK is 11.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, many thanks to [this post](http://scriptedpapers.com/2015/02/12/android-action-bar-and-overflow-menu-customization-with-theme-appcompat/) of [scriptedpapers](http://scriptedpapers.com/), I found out that I should use `android:dropDownListViewStyle`, not `android:popupMenuStyle`.
(Total misunderstanding of the concept, what a shame :)) )

now my style is like:

```
    </resources><resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

        <style name="CustomTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
            <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/CustomTheme.ActionBar</item>
            <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/CustomTheme.ActionBar</item>
            <item name="android:actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/CustomTheme.ActionBar.ActionOverflowButtonStyle</item>
            <item name="actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/CustomTheme.ActionBar.ActionOverflowButtonStyle</item>
            <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/CustomTheme.ActionBar.DropDownListViewStyle</item>
            <item name="dropDownListViewStyle">@style/CustomTheme.ActionBar.DropDownListViewStyle</item>
            <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
            <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
        </style>

        <style name="CustomTheme.ActionBar.DropDownListViewStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ListView.DropDown">
            <item name="android:background">@drawable/action_bar_background</item>
        </style>
        ...
    </resources>
```